# Regex for capturing only till the first find of a char in a Java string

Tags: java, regex, string

This piece of code

```
String Str = new String("${project_loc:A}/Foo.yaml;${project_loc:B}/Bar.yaml");
System.out.println(Str.replaceFirst("[$][{].*[}]/", ""));
```

prints

```
Bar.yaml
```

while what I am trying to achieve is:

```
Foo.yaml;${project_loc:B}/Bar.yaml
```

Why is it stopping at second closing braces i.e. `}`, not at first?

What regex exp can be passed to `replaceFirst()` to achieve the desired result?

FYI: I tried few things at https://regex101.com/ but couldn't find any success.

Comment: Use `\\$\\{.[^}]*}/` for your search regex as `.*` is greedy

Comment: use this :   System.out.println(Str.replaceFirst("[$][{].*?[}]/", "")); . The additional ? makes the expression non-greedy. Else by default regex patterns are greedy matches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dot-asterisk `.*` will consume everything, including as many `}`s as it can find; use `[^}]*` to stop at the first `}` instead:

```
System.out.println(Str.replaceFirst("[$][{][^}]*[}]/", ""));
```

[Demo 1.](https://ideone.com/4uFudk)

You could also use reluctant quantifier `.*?`:

```
System.out.println(Str.replaceFirst("[$][{].*?[}]/", ""));
```

[Demo 2.](https://ideone.com/ul2S2k)